# JavaScript Reference XML File

Tags: javascript, xml, file, text, reference

I am using JavaScript to post an XML request to an online database.  When I was testing the JavaScript, I used a single sample record which successfully posted.  Now, I need to reference a separate XML file that has 6,000+ records (stored either locally or on a network drive).

I am trying to determine the best approach for this, but have been unsuccessful thus far.  I have referenced other questions such as [Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file), but I am getting an `Access Denied` error, most likely due to cross-domain requests (even though I have changed my Security settings).

Is there any way to accomplish this?  My external XML file is simply the `<root>` and then the records, nothing more.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File, if you put an `input type="file"` in your HTML document you can select a local file and then the browser exposes it to Javascript.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for the response!  This would require the user to select the file every time though, correct?  I would like to reach a point where this JavaScript can run automatically at a designated frequency.

Comment: Without user interaction I don't think a browser will allow the file system access, unless you write a browser extension or the browser allows to to somehow grant privileges to the script.

Comment: @MartinHonnen do you think it'd be more plausible to upload the XML to the same site where the JavaScript HTML file is located? I am not quite sure what format to upload the XML (either .xml, .txt. or .htm) in order to read all of the records.